# Fade in items individually on a canvas

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

I would like to animate individual rectangles. I am trying to Fade In a rectangle independently. I want to create FadeIn(rectangle) and FadeOut(Rectangle) functions where I can pass a rectangle to fade in individual items.

I have seen https://codepen.io/mattsrinc/pen/YzPZbWw however, that's having multiple render loops, changing colors,etc. I am trying to make only FadeIn and FadeOut functions.

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>


var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var i = 0;
requestAnimationFrame(test);
requestAnimationFrame(test1);

function test() {
    i += 0.002;
    i = i < 0 ? 0 : i;
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 75, 50);
    ctx.globalAlpha = i;
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 75, 50);
    requestAnimationFrame(test);
}

function test1() {
    i += 0.002;
    i = i < 0 ? 0 : i;
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fillRect(100, 60, 75, 50);
    ctx.globalAlpha = i;
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.fillRect(100, 60, 75, 50);
    requestAnimationFrame(test1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one `requestAnimationFrame`, use `clearRect` instead of drawing a white rect, clamp the alpha value between 0 and 1 so you won't get weird flickering.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var blueAlpha = 0;
var blueSetp = 0.02; // Blue velocity
var redAlpha = 0;
var redStep = 0.01; // Red velocity

const calmp = (value, min, max) => Math.max(min, Math.min(value, max));

requestAnimationFrame(render);

function render() {   

    // Setting Blue Alpha
    if(blueAlpha < 0 || blueAlpha > 1) 
      blueSetp = blueSetp * -1; // inverse blue
    blueAlpha += blueSetp;
    
    // Drawing Blue
    ctx.globalAlpha = calmp(blueAlpha, 0, 1);
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.clearRect(100, 60, 75, 50); // Use clearRect
    ctx.fillRect(100, 60, 75, 50);

    // Setting Red alpha
    if(redAlpha < 0 || redAlpha > 1)
      redStep = redStep * -1; // inverse red
    redAlpha += redStep;
    
    // Drawing Red
    ctx.globalAlpha = calmp(redAlpha, 0, 1);
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.clearRect(20, 20, 75, 50);
    ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 75, 50);
    
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
```